# Use Toast inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, toast

I'm trying to show a Toast Message when user click on a Button inside a Fragment. The problem is I cannot access the activity to show the Toast on it.

Here's the source of `Fragment`:

```
    public class FrgTimes extends Fragment
    {
        ScrollView sv;
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            if (container == null) { return null; }

            sv = (ScrollView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_times, container, false);

            btnTime1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            //******  HERE's the PROBLEM  ********
            Toast.makeText(<The Activity>, "Please long press the key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG );

            }});

            return sv;
        }
```

and Here's what I've been tried.

```
Toast.makeText( getActivity()  , ...
Toast.makeText( getView().getContext()  , ...
Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext()  , ...
Toast.makeText( sv.getContext()  , ...
Toast.makeText( sv.getRootView().getContext()  , ...
```

In Debug I can see that all of these codes run without any exception but no `TOAST` being displayed.

Comment: Which one of your multiple tries is more appropriate? `getActivity()` or `getView.getContext()` or ...  Thanks.

Comment: The problem was something else as described in best answer.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You are not calling `show()` on the `Toast` you are creating with `makeText()`.

Comment: This little **`SHOW`** takes more than 3 hours of me. Thanks, now everything seems beautiful.

Comment: That's my standard error - good news is that Lint detects this error as of SDK20.

Comment: STupid Me  ..Thats was my mistake..i didnot call show()

Comment: Oooops! it is too easy to do such a mistake!

Comment: I've used the correct syntax but toast didn't show up in mobile device. I've tried in emulator, it worked.

Answer (score 69):

As stated by alfo888_ibg:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
   Toast.makeText(activity,"Text!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Just do:

```
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Text!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

this worked for me.

Comment: I am using the toast inside the onCreateView of the Fragment's java file. Toast is being called two times.Why? ```Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Entered onCreateView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();``` i have also used the getActivity() in place of getContext()... same issue

Answer (score 24):

To help another people with my same problem, 
the complete answer to Use Toast inside Fragment is:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Toast.makeText(activity,"Text!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

When making a toast in fragment do as following:

`Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

When class is extending fragment it is necessary to use **getActivity()** since fragment is a *subclass* of activity.

Cheerse

Comment: Fragment is a subclass of Object, check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html, if it was subclass of activity you could use 'this' instead

Answer (score 11):

You can get the current activity with getActivity()

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Toast your message" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 9):

Making a Toast inside Fragment

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Text Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

OR

```
    Activity activityObj = this.getActivity();

    Toast.makeText(activityObj, "Your Text Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

OR

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Your Text Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using kotlin then the context will be already defined in the fragment. So just use that context. Try the following code to show a toast message.

```
Toast.makeText(context , "your_text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 2):

When calling Toast inside android fragment:

```
1. Activity mActivity=this.getActivity();  

2. Toast.makeText(mActivity,"Text you want to display",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This works for me.

Comment: as we can see the user did not call the `show()` method after the `Toast`'s closing. simple you can comment this.

Answer (score 1):

user2564789 said it right
But you can also use `this` in the place of `getActivity()`
which will make your toast look like this

```
     Toast.makeText(this,"Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple [Fragment] subclass.
Kotlin!
contextA - is a parent (main) Activity. Set it on create object.

```
class Start(contextA: Context) : Fragment() {

var contextB: Context = contextA;

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val fl = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false)

    // only thet variant is worked on me
    fl.button.setOnClickListener { view -> openPogodaUrl(view) }

    return fl;
}

fun openPogodaUrl(view: View) {        
    try {
        pogoda.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() { // pogoda - is a WebView
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                view?.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }
        }
        pogoda.loadUrl("http://exemple.com/app_vidgets/pogoda.html");
    }
    catch (e: Exception)
    {
        Toast.makeText(contextB, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Using Kotlin**

```
Toast.makeText(view!!.context , "your_text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin android
Toast.makeText(activity!!, "Your Text Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin :

Inside Activity:
Toast.makeText(this, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

Inside Fragment:
Toast.makeText(context, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

Inside Adapter:
Toast.makeText(context.context, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

Here first context is Activity or Fragment instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            CharSequence text = "Message";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Unique Approach

(Will work for Dialog, Fragment, Even Util class etc...)

#### `ApplicationContext.getInstance().toast("I am toast");`

Add below code in Application class accordingly.

```
public class ApplicationContext extends Application {

private static ApplicationContext instance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
}

public static void toast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```